# Errors creating html file using xml and xsl file (xslt 2.0) (Recoverable error I/O error reported by XML parser processing)

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

Im using the code below to generate html from a xml and xsl files. It was working fine for xslt 1.0, but now Im using xslt 2.0. And Im getting this error when execute the code below: `ERROR:  Unsupported XSL element 'for-each-group'.'`

Do you know how to fix this?

```
private static void createHtml(){
        try {
            TransformerFactory tf =TransformerFactory.newInstance();    
            Source xslFile =new StreamSource("test.xsl");
            Source xmlFile =new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml));

            String resultFile ="test.html";

            OutputStream htmlFile=new FileOutputStream(resultFile );
            Transformer trasform=tFactory.newTransformer(xslFile);
            trasform.transform(xmlFile, new StreamResult(htmlFile));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error.");
        }
 }
```

Im trying to do like this now:

```
TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File("test.xsl")));

transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(xml)),
                new StreamResult("test.html"));
```

And in the main method:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl")
```

And I get this error:

```
Recoverable error 
  I/O error reported by XML parser processing
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you getting the error about `for-each-group` and another error "I/O error reported by XML parser processing"? Can you show us a minimal but complete XML input and XSLT stylesheet for which you get the error? Also in your Java code, change the catch clause `System.out.println("Error.");` to `e.printStackTrace();` and show the complete stack trace in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reporting two different errors:

(a) ERROR:  Unsupported XSL element 'for-each-group'.'

(b) Recoverable error: I/O error reported by XML parser processing

It seems unlikely that you got these from the same run, so it's not clear what you were doing on each of these occasions to get two different errors.

The first error means that for some reason you have loaded an XSLT processor that doesn't support XSLT 2.0. The safest and fastest way to be sure of loading Saxon is to instantiate it directly:

```
TransformerFactory tfactory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
```

If you rely on the JAXP mechanisms there are all sorts of things that can go wrong, and it can also be very slow because it involves searching the classpath.

With the second error, you haven't given enough information to provide a full diagnosis. However, the fact that there's no filename in the message gives a clue: it means Saxon doesn't know the filename, and this is often because you have done something like:

```
Source xmlFile =new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml));
```

A StringReader itself will never give an I/O error. But if the XML that you are parsing contains a DTD reference, or references to other external entities, and if these are relative references, then the XML parser won't be able to resolve them because it doesn't have a base URI to work with. You can supply a base URI in the second argument of the StreamSource constructor.